# Problems with PDF generation

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm developing a specific part of my website which uses a sales report where my user(client) can consult it from.
It generates a report ordered by date and builds it dynamically with JQUERY AND PHP.

After that its enabled options such as print and generate PDF. The print part its already done and working perfectly but I'm having troubles with PDF generation part because I have to give as option 2 types of model for choosing.

First model is ok, despite it uses several lines on it, I still can manage it to generate as PDF using FPDF which is faster just because those lines is all in a certain pattern. I mean, it's always the same, the only difference would be the number of registers requested.

But the problem here is the second model which is totally variable even on columns making it hard to work with FPDF (I would have to build it line per line and that is unviable)

I've already tried several classes of converters from HTML to PDF like: DOMPDF, HTML2PDF, MPDF but they take a very long time processing when it's requested for big period of time for example.

So let's jump for my help request:

Or generate and save it in server while the user is searching for a specific period of time and when he clicks on model 2 (it will be already generated) he'll just get a link to a folder to download it directly.

Any idea or solution is welcome, I don't care if it will be hard to implement it.

I've found some APIs with DocRaptor that suits very well, good and fast but it's paid and this is unviable for me.

Comment: All the libraries you mention generate PDF dynamically using a class so it's a weird question. But you basically want to convert from HTML to PDF. Google for that and you'll find excellent tools like wkhtml2pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Peardoc, the firm I work for, provides a solution to convert static/dynamic HTML to PDF on password protected web applications. This service requires the user, who has signed in, to click a "save as PDF" link.

Demo: http://www.peardoc.com/sap_pro_demo.html

We also provide an API service (with async call facility) for HTML to PDF conversion.

Documentation: http://www.peardoc.com/docs/api-doc